# when i select the dropdown option as completed then comment field is compulsory required

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

The problem is, the javascript is not working. When i select the option from dropdown as completed the comment field is required this validation should be done on submit button.if any other option is used then comment field is not compulsory to fill it.

below is my code:index.php

```
    <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="new.php">

    <!-- Select Basic -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="selectbasic">Status</label>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <select id="status" name="status[]" class="form-control" >
          <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
          <option value="Work in process">Work in process</option>
          <option value="Completed">Completed</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Text input-->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Comment</label>  
      <div class="col-md-4">
      <input id="commentss" name="comment[]" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" /> 
      </div>
    </div>
<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-24">
    <div class="input_fields" style="color:black">
         <button class="add_field btn " onclick="incrementValue()" >Add More</button>
         <div>
         <input type="text" name="mytextt[]" hidden="" ></div>
</div>
</div>

    <button id="save_btn" name="save_btn" type="submit" onclick="validate();" class="btn btn-success" style="width: 10em;margin-left:10px">Save</button>
    </form>
```

javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function validate()
  {
    var input=document.getElementById("#status");
    var comm=document.getElementById('#commentss')
    var inputelement=input.value;
    if(inputelement=="Completed")
    {
      comm.required=true;
    }

  }
</script>
```

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field"); //Add button ID
    var wrapper_pre1         = $(".present_fields_1"); //Fields wrapper
    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();

        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
           $(wrapper).prepend('<div class="form-group"> <label class="col-md-4 control-label status" for="selectbasic" style="">Status</label><div class="col-md-6"><select id="status[]" name="status[]"  class="form-control status"><option value="Pending">Pending</option><option value="Work in process">Work in process</option><option value="Completed">Completed</option></select></div></div><div class="form-group"><label class="col-md-4 control-label comment" for="textinput" style="">Comment</label><div class="col-md-4"><input id="comment[]" name="comment[]" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md comment" style=""></div></div>')
}
 });
```

Comment: Use @DanielLane solution and also change var inputelement=input.value(); to `var inputelement=input.value;` as value isn't a function

Comment: I have updated my code can u just check it  .I have add more button which contain dropdown and comment field this script is not working inside the add more button@PhilS

Comment: You're mixing vanilla Javascript and jQuery now, you may as well leverage jQuery for your validation if you're loading the jQuery library. Your "Add more" button is adding a select item with an id of status[] which isn't valid and the javascript can't reference it, an ID attribute can only contain numbers, letters, underscores, full colon and a full stop i believe, and must be unique.

Answer (score 2):

You're calling getElementById using a hash symbol on the input. In this case #status and #commentss

To select by id, you will need to make the call without the hash.

```
document.getElementById('status');
```

The hash prefix is used for querySelector and to denote that the selection will be an id selector.

document.querySelector('#status');

Comment: I have taken id in javascript in this format  document.getElementById('status'). Still the javascript is not taking the comment field as reqiured when i select the status as completed @Daniel Lane

Answer (score 2):

Remove `onclick="validate();"` from button and add this code inside script tag:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#save_btn").click(function () {

            if ($("#status").val() == "Completed") {
                $("#commentss").attr("required", "required");
            }
        });
});
```